# Removing DOM element cancels other Event Listener

Tags: javascript, events, dom

https://jsbin.com/musahum/1/edit?html,js,console,output

```
    document.getElementById('myInput').addEventListener('blur', function(){
      if(document.getElementById('container')){
        document.getElementById('container').remove();
      }
      console.log('blur');  
    });

    document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function(evt){
      evt.preventDefault();
      console.log('click');
    });
```

**Problem:**
I have two event listeners(blur, click). The first event listener(blur) also removes an element(#container) from the DOM. When it is removed from the DOM, it cancels out the second event listener(click), preventing the click event.

**Steps to reproduce:**
 1. Click inside the input box so that it is in focus.
 2. Directly click the button.
 3. This should ideally trigger 'blur' event and then 'click' event.
 4. Notice that 'click' event is not triggered.

Comment: https://jsbin.com/musahum/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I get "blur" then "click" using Firefox and the #container is removed with the blur. What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome 56.0.2924.87. Issue is reproducible on Firefox as well. It doesn't work first time. It works second time onwards.

Comment: @Jaspero — Did you try my demo ? It is because, element is shifted up hence event is not invoked on that element..

Comment: Rayon, your link opens my version. I did notice the issue could be related to element shifting up after removal. If you move #container div below #myButton, it works. But, it seems weird that shifting elements unbinds listeners.

Comment: @Jaspero - your JS Bin works fine for me on Chrome (56.0.2924.87) and Firefox. I get "blur" then "click" in the console.

Comment: Chris, can you confirm you get both in the first click? I do get it when I repeat it again.